# -like with output

Tags: powershell, sql-like

Still trying to learn Powershell and having a problem with something simple that is not making sense as it works on other scripts I have written so must be missing something stupid.
Basically I need to determine if a Nic is Enabled but not attached to anything so I can then add another command to disable it.  I just need it to output True if it is already disabled.
The value .netconnectionstatus is coming back as 0 so I was expecting the -like command to 
I was using the $disabled on its own just to double check my output.

```
$disabled = gwmi win32_networkadapter | where {$_.PhysicalAdapter -eq "True"-and $_.netenabled -ne "True"}`
| % { '{0,10} {1,20}' -f $_.netenabled,$_.netconnectionstatus}
$disabled
$_.netconnectionstatus -like "0"
```

Comment: Did you try with `$_.netconnectionstatus -like 0` (without quotes)?

Comment: Yes. It gave me the same output. Netconnectionstatus is coming back with a 0 which $disabled confirms but I still get false either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -like and -match operators make sense only in string comparisons.
Here -eq would be best bet, w/o quotes if you expect integer. Also - if you have boolean value, there is no need to compare it to anything. Here if you would change: `$_.NetEnabled -ne 'False'` you will get exactly same results... use: `where { $_.PhysicalAdapter -and (-not $_.NetEnabled)}` instead. If you ever decide to change it, you want shoot yourself in a foot because of the way PS treats strings ([bool]'False' -eq $true).

Also: your $_ is blank outside foreach-object scriptblock. Thus $false you get as result.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Worked a charm and so much easier than how I was trying to do it and thanks for setting me straight on the $_.